# Inserting auto dash at a particular place in a string using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hi I have this string `89   05  0342`  . I want to convert it to `89-05-0342` using regex .
I am using below code but its inserting like `89-05-03-42`. Can anybody help me to get the regex proper to make the final string like `89-05-0342`

My code

```
function copyPasteHandler() {                                  //copy paste handler for textbox
                   var $this = $(this);
                   setTimeout(function () {

                       var Test = $this.val().replace(/ /g, '');            
                       alert(Test);

                       if (Test.length < 10) {
                           Test = Test.match(new RegExp('.{1,2}', 'g')).join("-");
                       }
                       $this.val(Test);
                   }, 10); 

               }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to replace spaces that lie between two digits with a dash, then you can use this:

```js
alert(' 89 05 0342 '.replace(/(\d) (?=\d)/g, '$1-' )); // alerts ' 89-05-0342 '
```

This solution ensures that any other whitespace, including leading and trailing whitespace if present, will not be touched.

**Edit:** Based on your comments, I think what you want is to remove leading and trailing whitespace, and replace all inner whitespace with a dash, but only if the equivalent string with *no* whitespace is less than 10 characters. You can do that as follows:

```js
var str = ' 89   05  0342 ';
str = str.replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,''); // remove leading/trailing whitespace
if (str.replace(/\s/g,'').length < 10) { // str length without whitespace must be < 10
  str = str.replace(/\s+/g,'-'); // replace all extents of whitespace with a single dash
}
alert(str); // alerts '89-05-0342'
```

Comment: can you please add for leading space like "   89        05     0342  " ?

Comment: i want to replace every single space . leading/trailing/inbetween spaces . At the end the final string shall be 89-05-0342 . There should be some checking like number of characters is not more than 10 after removing the spaces too . sorry that i dint mention the later in my question ..

Thanks man for your quick reply . waiting for the solution for the above one too .

Comment: Sorry, I'm not 100% clear on the requirement. If you want all of leading/trailing/inner spaces to be replaced with a dash, then `" 89 05 0342 "` would become `"-89-05-0342-"`. Is that really what you want? It sounds like you don't want leading or trailing dashes.

Comment: yes u got it right . i dont want leading and trailing dashes.

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert( '89 05 0342'.replace(/\s/g, '-') );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to replace:

```
var Test = $this.val().replace(/\s+/g, '-');
```

This will replace one or multiple spaces between numbers with single hyphen.